# Angular2 Sytling Nested Component not working

Tags: angular

i´ve got a Timeline where i display Items
I wanted to move the item to another component.

Ao i made a new component with an input and it works but not 100%:

This is a screenshot when im not using the subcomponent:

[NORMAL](http://abload.de/image.php?img=normalsvumf.png)

The following picture shows the view in a subcomponent

[BROKEN](http://abload.de/image.php?img=unnormalrkuyg.jpg)

I tried to use it as an HTML Tag and even in a `<li>` tag as an attribute.
Nothing Works

EDIT: Here is the Plunker [PLUNKER](https://embed.plnkr.co/4oRPuvYCRADmW7a8le2S/)

The Component :

```
<div *ngIf="item.participated">
    <div class="timeline-badge success">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="!item.participated">
    <div class="timeline-badge warning">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-panel">
    <div class="timeline-heading">
      <h4 class="timeline-title">Nächstes Essen am {{ item.Date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy' }}</h4>
      <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> erstellt am:  {{ item.Created | date:'dd.MM.yyyy' }} durch {{ item.CreatedBy }}</small></p>
      <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Teilnehmer: {{ item.Orders?.length }}</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-body">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Template for if user has not participated in the appointment -->
        <div *ngIf="!item.participated" class="col-md-3">
          <div>
            <button [disabled]="!canParticipate(item)" (click)="navigateToAppointment(item.Id)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="item.participated" class="col-md-3">
          <div>
            <button [disabled]="!canParticipate(item)" (click)="deleteOrder(item.Id)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Template for if user is admin -->
        <div *ngIf="IsAdmin" class="col-md-3">
          <div>
            <button [disabled]="item.Orders?.length > 0" (click)="deleteAppointment(item)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is the main componnent:

```
<ul class="timeline">
        <li app-comp [item]=item [class.timeline-inverted]="i%2 != 0" *ngFor="let item of appointments | orderBy : ['Date'] | async  ;let i = index">
</li>
<ul>
```

i tried this even as a normal component:

```
<ul class="timeline">
        <li [class.timeline-inverted]="i%2 != 0" *ngFor="let item of appointments | orderBy : ['Date'] | async  ;let i = index">
          <app-comp [item]=item>
          </app-comp>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please upload the image directly to this question so that the ads don't show up when we try to view the screen prints or may be you can create a plunk?

It would become easier for someone to read your question.

Comment: Hi, sure : https://embed.plnkr.co/4oRPuvYCRADmW7a8le2S/

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem :

in the CSS the Timeline i had a .timeline > li > .timeline-panel
so everything depends on the li element.

Angular renders an own element on this so the direct item  is beetwen the classes and the css style is not working anymore.
I removed the direct dependency in the css and now it works !